# restart subheading numbering in word created using openxml

Tags: excel, ms-word, c#-3.0, openxml-sdk

I generated word document extracting content from Excel sheet using OpenXML & I've applied style to many paragraphs .I am getting the output as

1. heading 1

   1.1 heading 2

   1.2 heading 3
2. heading 1

   1.3 heading

1.4 heading

I need to do **restart numbering in  subheadings**. How do I do that in OpenXML?

The output should come like

1. heading 1

   1.1 heading 2

   1.2 heading 3
2. heading 1

   2.1 heading

2.2 heading